# Python 'cannot import name'

Tags: python, python-import

So i have structure like this

[image]

And i want to import userlist.py from server.py. 
Server py:

```
import socket

from server import userlist #<-- error here

class Server():
    def __init__(self,port):
```

Other files in *server* don't have any refferences to *userlist*. It says *cannot import name userlist*

If i change import to

```
from server.userlist import Userlist
```

it says:
 'server' is not a package

Comment: Hmm.  Sounds as if the package `server` isn't in your search path - this may be an IDE issue.  Try `from .userlist import Userlist`.  This will do a relative import.  If that succeeds, then you need to add the `server` package to your search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just

```
import userlist
```

When you are importing a file (module) in the same directory, all you need to do is import the name of that file without the `.py` part.